# How HTML5 offline cache works with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, caching, html, offline, master-pages

There are MasterPage.master in my ASP.NET application

My manifest file dose not work:

CACHE

MANIFEST CACHE:

MasterPage.master

Please, tell how should I correctly write MasterPage in my manifest file?

Comment: Why would you need to cache MasterPage.master?  It's not a page that's ever sent to the client.  Do you have any pages which are *using* MasterPage.master?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try and cache your Masterpage. If you want to cache any pages that the Master Page uses, instead add the manifest attribute to the HTML tag on your Master Page. That way the HTML page will be cached.

[image: Application Cache]

If you need more information on this, I have written an article about MVC and the Application Cache - it should give you a pretty good idea of what you are trying to achieve.

http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/mvc-and-the-html5-application-cache/59

Similarly, try http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html